# How do you make "em" scale with zoom level on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox, if I zoom in by hitting `CTRL +` everything grows proportionally as expected. However, on Chrome, only measurements specified in `px` grow. Measurements specified in `em` do not grow. How would I make Chrome's zoom behave like Firefox's?

**Original Zoom Level on Either Browser:**

[image]

**Zoomed In on Firefox:**

[image]

**Zoomed In on Chrome:**

[image]

Here's an example of the CSS for the text shown above. The reason why I mix `em` and `px` is because I would like to scale structural things (defined with em) without scaling aesthetic things (defined with px). For example, If I needed to use the Facebook button on another page at double the size, I just set the containing element to `font-size:2.0em`. This would multiply all structural sizes by 2, while leaving the aesthetic sizes untouched.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```